# Cannot turn on DRS on vSphere server with generated python code

Tags: python, vsphere, pyvmomi

This is the code generated by the code capture feature.

```
from pyVmomi import vim

spec = vim.cluster.ConfigSpecEx()
spec.drsConfig = vim.cluster.DrsConfigInfo()
spec.drsConfig.defaultVmBehavior = "fullyAutomated"
spec.drsConfig.scaleDescendantsShares = 'disabled'
spec.drsConfig.vmotionRate = 1
spec.drsConfig.enabled = True
spec.drsConfig.enableVmBehaviorOverrides = True
spec_drsConfig_option_0 = vim.option.OptionValue()
spec_drsConfig_option_0.value = '1'
spec_drsConfig_option_0.key = 'TryBalanceVmsPerHost'
spec_drsConfig_option_1 = vim.option.OptionValue()
spec_drsConfig_option_1.key = 'MaxVcpusPerCore'
spec.drsConfig.option = [spec_drsConfig_option_0,
spec_drsConfig_option_1]
spec.proactiveDrsConfig = vim.cluster.ProactiveDrsConfigInfo()
spec.proactiveDrsConfig.enabled = True
spec.dpmConfig = vim.cluster.DpmConfigInfo()
spec.dpmConfig.hostPowerActionRate = 3
spec.dpmConfig.enabled = False
modify = True
managedObject.ReconfigureComputeResource_Task(spec, modify)   # ClusterComputeResource-domain-c8


Error: C:\python>python drsTestThing.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\drsTestThing.py", line 38, in <module>
    managedObject.ReconfigureComputeResource_Task(spec, modify)   # ClusterComputeResource-domain-c8
NameError: name 'managedObject' is not defined
```

So far I gave determined that the return of the ReconfigureComputeResource_Task function is a Task object according to this https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/da47f910-60ac-438b-8b9b-6122f4d14524/16b7274a-bf8b-4b4c-a05e-746f2aa93c8c/doc/vim.ComputeResource.html and it must be called by a cluster object.

My issue is I don't understand how to make to make a cluster object and how that connects to vSphere and changes the configuration of the cluster.

Currently I am connecting to the host using SmartConnect from the pyVim library. I also have this working with powerCLI but the connect-vi server method hangs so I would like to accomplish this task with python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never established the cluster (or [ClusterComputeResource](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.ClusterComputeResource.html)) as the `managedObject` variable. That should have been done prior to creating the `spec` variable and may have been missed from the Code Capture output.

Comment: I noticed that, there wasn't anything on the code capture that defined that variable. I noticed this in [regards to the cluster](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.Folder.html#createClusterEx) but I'm not sure how to go about properly creating that variable. I just found [this](https://www.programcreek.com/python/?code=vmware%2Fpyvmomi-community-samples%2Fpyvmomi-community-samples-master%2Fsamples%2Flist_dc_datastore_info.py), would using retrieve_content() get my the reference to the MO?

Comment: FWIW, here's how it looks in my Code Capture output: 

```
$spec = New-Object VMware.Vim.ClusterConfigSpecEx
$spec.DrsConfig = New-Object VMware.Vim.ClusterDrsConfigInfo
...
$_this = Get-View -Id 'ClusterComputeResource-domain-c7'
$_this.ReconfigureComputeResource_Task($spec, $modify)
```

Comment: That looks like the powerCLI output. That works for the most part but the connect-vi server cmdlet can hang and I want to avoid that. This is the python output I get: 
# managedObject.RetrieveDasAdvancedRuntimeInfo()   
# spec = vim.cluster.ConfigSpecEx()
# modify = True # managedObject.ReconfigureComputeResource_Task(spec, modify)   # ClusterComputeResource-domain-c8  I had to click around a little bit when capturing the code to get the managed object reference but it still errors out and I'm not sure why. It appears I need to instantiate the ClusterResource variable but I'm not sure how

Comment: ah, sorry about that, the dropdown changed between recordings. You might be able to update it with the following: managedObject = get_obj(content, [vim.ClusterComputeResource], inputs['cluster_name'])

Comment: I'll give that a spin and let you know how it goes. It seems like this side of VMware isn't well documented. Thanks for all the help!